# Blender duplicates the Material each time I duplicate the object

Tags: materials

I have a multi-part project with all the same materials. When I copy the object, it creates another material with the same assets, but a different name:

[image]

How can I delete them all and use the same material for all objects?

Comment: what method do you use to duplicate your object, it should not create a new material

Comment: He must be using Ctrl+V and Ctrl+C, that way it does

Comment: i use ctrl+c, ctrl+v. every time i do it, blender duplicate the material

Answer (score 0):

You should duplicate objects with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
This way it won't duplicate *Materials*.

---

**But if you still want to duplicate objects like you did before:**

You'll need to delete the unwanted *Materials*, all but one and then link that to all the other objects.

**And how to do that:**

1. Go to the outliner on the top rigth (the place with your *Objects*, *Cameras*, and *Ligths*) and on the dropdown choose *Blender File*
2. Navigate to the material folder and select unwanted the left click and choose delete (here <kbd>X</kbd> will not work like on the rest of *Blender*)

Comment: Would *remap users* work with multiple materials selected?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what Remap Users is inside of Blender